# Error during PIVOT in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create pivot where row is Brand and SKU, sum is qty for column YYMM, but I'm not sure why it is throwing an error. Please help.

Code:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
    SKU VARCHAR(10),
    YYMM VARCHAR(50),
    BRAND VARCHAR(50),  
    QTY INT
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE
    SELECT '104591168', '2015-January', 'abott',    2 UNION ALL
    SELECT '104580709', '2016-January', 'GSK',  2  UNION ALL
    SELECT '104720038', '2017-January', 'RANBAXCY', 2  UNION ALL
    SELECT '10467011A', '2018-January', 'abott',    2  UNION ALL
    SELECT '104590691', '2019-January', 'abott',    10
```

Pivot code:

```
select *
from
    (select 
         BRAND, sku, QTY, YYMM
     from @TABLE) src
pivot
    (sum(QTY)
     for [Year Month]
```

Comment: You are missing `)` at the end of your query, but there is also problem with `for [Year Month]`. Please edit your question add error and desired result. Also you can read about `PIVOT` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot)).

Comment: ***WHAT*** error?!? Don't tease us with *there is an error* and then you're not actually **telling us** what it is - remember: we **CANNOT** read your screen, nor your mind - you'll have to **tell us** and provide it here so we can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to finish your query.

Please see the bottom of [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) article for `PIVOT` examples.

I would guess that you wanted your query to look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT BRAND, sku, QTY, YYMM
    FROM @TABLE
) AS src
PIVOT(
    sum(QTY)
    for [YYMM] IN( [2015-January], [2016-January], [2017-January] /* add other moneths here */ )
) AS Pivoted
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make it as Dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @Column  NVARCHAR(max), 
        @Column2 NVARCHAR(max), 
        @Sql     NVARCHAR(max) 

SELECT @Column = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' 
                                        + Quotename(Cast(yymm AS VARCHAR(20))) 
                        FROM   #table 
                        FOR xml path ('')), 1, 1, '') 

SELECT @Column2 = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + 'ISNULL(' 
                                         + Quotename(Cast(yymm AS VARCHAR(20))) 
                                         + ',' 
                                         + '''0''' + ') AS ' 
                                         + Quotename(Cast(yymm AS VARCHAR(20))) 
                         FROM   #table 
                         FOR xml path ('')), 1, 1, '') 

SET @Sql='

SELECT BRAND ,sku,'+@Column2+'
FROM(
    SELECT *
    FROM #TABLE
) AS src
PIVOT(
    sum(QTY)
    for [YYMM] IN('+@Column+')
) AS Pivoted
'
PRINT  @Sql

EXEC(@Sql)
```

Result

```
BRAND       sku         2015-January    2016-January    2017-January    2018-January    2019-January
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abott       104590691   0               0                   0               0               10
abott       104591168   2               0                   0               0               0
abott       10467011A   0               0                   0               2               0
GSK         104580709   0               2                   0               0               0
RANBAXCY    104720038   0               0                   2               0               0
```